# How to Make Java Open a Batch File in Same Command Prompt Window

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I am trying to make a console-based Java application that starts some batch scripts that do some other irrelevant things. Presently, I just want to find the proof of concept

I have tried to use the following code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start pathtomybatch.bat");
```

This works fine until I turn it into a `.jar` file and attempt to execute it. Then it opens the batch file in a new command prompt window, which I don't want it to do. I want to open the batch file in the same window that my Java program is running in. I read about the `start` command on [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/bb491005.aspx) and [SS64](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) and found out that apparently adding changing `start` to `start /b` would open the program in the same command prompt window. However, when I try to run this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start /b pathtomybatch.bat");
```

NetBeans says `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` for both lines of code, but when I try the second line of code, no command prompt window opens and my batch file doesn't get started.

I want to know how I can make Java open that batch file within the same command prompt window without stopping the Java application or waiting for it to finish.

Also, as a tiny extra request, could someone tell me if I could do the same for an `.exe` file?

I'm on Windows 7, but I want this app to work for people using Vista or newer.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Wouldn't you juts want the script to run and then close?

Comment: I do not have netbeans but I find it hard to believe it does not execute the batch file. Does netbeans have some way of allocating a console or using its output window as console for the inferior process?

Comment: @RileyCarney The Java application will do other things after the batch finishes executing.

Comment: Seems like it would be easier to have a Windows batch file do the Windows commands, and then the batch file would start your Java application to do the other things.   Use the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

The extra window is coming from the start command you initiate. See https://www.windows-commandline.com/cmd-start-command/

A better pattern is to use

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c pathtomybatch.bat");
```

Then make sure you loop until p.exitValue() no longer throws an exception (which means the process has exited), and while looping copy all available bytes from p.getOutputStream() and p.getErrorStream() to System.out and/or System.err.